# yowsup-cli: registration procedure failing, something unknown is "missing"

Tags: whatsapp, yowsup

I am using yowsup-cli, and it prints the following when I run "yowsup-cli version" ...

```
yowsup-cli v2.0.13
Using yowsup v2.4
```

I am trying to perform the registration as specified in the yowsup documentation, as follows. However, it fails.

First, I entered this command, and I indeed got a code back via SMS ...

```
yowsup-cli registration --requestcode sms --phone 1XXXXXXXXXX --cc 1 --mcc 310 --mnc 260
```

I then entered this command using the code I got back (shown as "AAA-BBB"), but it failed ...

```
yowsup-cli registration --register AAA-BBB --phone 1XXXXXXXXXX --cc 1
```

This is the error message I received ...

```
status: fail
reason: missing
```

What I did above is exactly what is described in the yowsup documentation, here: https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/yowsup-cli-2.0#yowsup-cli-registration%29 (see the commands listed under "Example:").

Note that I get the same failure when I add the MNC and MCC info to the "--register" command.

Does anyone know why this registration procedure is failing, and what might be "missing" in what I'm doing?

Note that the MCC and MNC I specified are what I found when looking up my cell provider (T-Mobile, USA).

Also, note that I am able to run WhatsApp with no problems from my mobile device, as well as via their web interface.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

you do not have to put "-" in your otp/code. it will be a plain sms code

```
yowsup-cli registration --register AAABBB --phone 1XXXXXXXXXX --cc 1
```

i hope it works